# C# Generics - Resolved - How to solve the ambiguous compiler error calling a method of passed generic type; e.g., IXList.Head() and IYList.Head()

Tags: c#, templates, generics, constraints, ambiguous

The emphasis of my question is with **C# Generics** and the passing of the interface **IXList** -or- **IYList** to this '**GetAllValues**()' method. The goal is common code for calling `GetAllValues<IXList>()` -or- `GetAllValues<IYList>()`.

09-21-13 Follow up:
I have learned that: `where Z : IXList, IYList` means that Z is of type `IXList` and `ITList` -- given this understanding one might try `where Z : class` - this is at best a lateral step of still not working because then `Z.anything` ... `anything` is not found, the compiler is clueless about `Z`...

Can the actual type of Z passed be tested and then conditional run-time 
code pick correct casted `list` to call .Head(), .Get(), and .Next() accordingly?
e.g.,   `((IXList)list).Head();`   -or-   `((IYList)list).Head();` **[[ Yes it is possible, please see 2nd answer with code below dated 09-24-13.]]**

09-29-13 Follow up:
And finally, answer/solution **#3** posted below moves the final solution to a more object oriented one. And thus, this 3rd solution **renders moot** my initial question on how to ask the type of generic  and how to solve the compiler ambiguity error encountered initially. **[[ Please see answer/solution  #3, with code below dated 09-29-13.]]**

```
    internal static IEnumerable<int> GetAllValues<Z>(Z list)
        where Z : IXList, IYList
    {
        try
        {
            list.Head();        // Error 344 - The call is ambiguous between the following
                                // methods or properties: 'IXList.Head()' and 'IYList.Head()'   
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        do
        {
            IntPtr lineItemPointer;
            int x = list.Get();     // Error 345 - The call is ambiguous between the following
                                    // methods or properties: 'IXList.Get()' and 'IYList.Get()' 

            yield return x;

            try
            {
                list.Next();        // Error 346 -The call is ambiguous between the following
                                    // methods or properties: 'IXList.Next()' and 'IYList.Next()'   
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                yield break;
            }
        } while (true);
    }
```

Comment: Casting to the interface you want in each particular case would work...

Comment: This sounds like a place `dynamic` might be useful, of course there are other implications to using dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution #3: by-far the best, no need to cast anything, no need to ask the type of the input list (repeatedly), much much cleaner. Please compare with Answer/Solution #2 above.

**(#3)** accomplishes exactly the goal I was seeking, common code for the logic that process either IXList or IYList. And as an extension method the user gets the 'GetAllItems' typed version desired...

```
    internal static IEnumerable<IXOutList> GetAllLineItems(this IXList list)
    {
        TListEnumeratorBase genList = new IXListEnum(list);
        return GetAllLineItemsGeneric<IXOutList>(genList);
    }


    internal static IEnumerable<IYOutList> GetAllLineItems(this IYList list)
    {
        TListEnumeratorBase genList = new IYListEnum(list);
        return GetAllLineItemsGeneric<IYOutList>(genList);
    }                                                                                                                                   


    private static IEnumerable<Zout> GetAllLineItemsGeneric<Zout>(TListEnumeratorBase genList)
        where Zout : class     
    {
        try
        {
            genList.Head();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        Guid guid = Marshal.GenerateGuidForType(typeof(Zout));

        do
        {
            Zout rec = null;
            try
            {
                IntPtr lineItemPointer;
                lineItemPointer = genList.GetTxnItem(ref guid);
                rec = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(lineItemPointer) as Zout;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                yield break;
            }

            if (rec != null)
                yield return rec;
            else
                yield break;

            try
            {
                genList.Next();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                yield break;
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    public abstract class TListEnumeratorBase
    {
        public abstract void Head();
        public abstract void Next();
        public abstract IntPtr GetTxnItem(ref Guid guid);
    }

    public class IXListEnum : TListEnumeratorBase
    {
        IXList _list;
        public IXListEnum(IXList list)
        {
            _list = list;
        }
        public override void Head()
        {
            _list.Head();
        }
        public override void Next()
        {
            _list.Next();
        }
        public override IntPtr GetTxnItem(ref Guid guid)
        {
            IntPtr lineItemPointer;
            _list.Get(ref guid, out lineItemPointer);
            return lineItemPointer;
        }
    }

    public class IYListEnum : TListEnumeratorBase
    {
        IYList _list;
        public IYListEnum(IYList list)
        {
            _list = list;
        }
        public override void Head()
        {
            _list.Head();
        }
        public override void Next()
        {
            _list.Next();
        }
        public override IntPtr GetTxnItem(ref Guid guid)
        {
            IntPtr lineItemPointer;
            _list.Get(ref guid, out lineItemPointer);
            return lineItemPointer;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As your code is now your template requires Z to be class AND IXList AND IYList so you will not achieve your goal with this code. To do that you need a common interface for IXList and IYList as you can see below IMyList. If you introduce that you simply change the where statement to:

```
where Z : class, IMyList
```

consider even if you really need the class constraint.

---

As to ambiguity:

If you can modify interfaces IXList, IYList then you can exclude those common parts to separate one and inherit from the new one:

```
interface IMyList
{
    void Head();
    //....
}

inteface  IXList :IMyList { //....
inteface  IYList :IMyList { //....
```

This will resolve ambiguity

---

If for what ever reason you cannot do that your only option is to cast on one of your interfaces on every call

```
((IXList)list).Head();
```

this will resolve ambiguity but is not what you wanted in the first place. If you cannot introduce new interface then only option to have this common looking code would be to implement this extension method for each list kind.

Comment: Very interesting and helpful,thank you...

The 'class' constraint isn't need, you are right.

However I thought that

 where Z : IXList, IYList 

was saying that 'list' was of type 'Z' and 'Z' is constrained to be of type IXList or IYList

and the compile Error I am getting is saying that it could not pick between making code to run list.Head() when list was passed in as IXList vs. when list is passed in as IYLIST.

Can the actual type of Z passed be tested for and conditional 
code be made to call the correct casted version of .Head(), .Get(), and .Next()?

Comment: comment out code inside your method return null and try calling it. You can pass inside only classes that are IXList and IYList not or. For example class HList:IXList,IYList{} which is not what you want. In other words where clause ads MUST BE ALL OF THOSE restriction. So when Z is at the same time IXList and IYList then compiler cannot say which method you want to call.

Comment: Good day Rafal, I believe I agree Reducing to this:[br]
        internal static IEnumerable<int> GetAllValues<Z>(Z list)[<br/>]
                where Z : class<br/>
{<br/>
list.Head();<br/>  // Error - 'Z' does not contain a definition for 'Head' no extension<br/> // method 'Head' accepting ...<br/>
}<br/> 

Is there a way to code testing for what type 'Z' is at runtime and then casting it to the correct type and then being have to call .Head()?

Comment: Ach :) you should really invest some time in understanding basics of generic types.

Comment: If the documentation were complete and written fully, I wouldn't be asking here.

Answer (score 0):

The following accomplishes exactly the goal I was seeking, common code for the logic that process either IXList or IYList. Yea!

And as an extension method the user gets the 'GetAllItems' typed version desired...

`var landRecs = _land.MainXList().GetAllItems();`

`var landAltRecs = _land.AlternateYList().GetAllItems();`

```
    internal static IEnumerable<Iint> GetAllItems(this IXList list)
    {
        return GetAllItemsGeneric<Iint, IXList>(list);
    }

    internal static IEnumerable<string> GetAllItems(this IYList list)
    {
        return GetAllItemsGeneric<string, IYList>(list);
    }                                                                                                                                   

    private static IEnumerable<Zout> GetAllItemsGeneric<Zout, T>(T list)
        where Zout : class      // (string -or- int)  -or-  (IReadOnlyTxnMisc or ITxnMisc) etc.
        where T : class         // IYList  -or- IXList  
    {
        try
        {
            DoHeadforList<T>(list);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        Guid guid = Marshal.GenerateGuidForType(typeof(Zout));

        do
        {
            Zout rec = null;
            try
            {
                IntPtr itemPointer;
                itemPointer = DoGetItemforList<T>(list, ref guid);
                rec = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(itemPointer) as Zout;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                yield break;
            }

            if (rec != null)
            {
                yield return rec;
            }
            else
            {
                yield break;
            }

            try
            {
                DoNextforList<T>(list);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                yield break;
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    private enum IListType
    {
        X,
        Y,
        Unknown
    }

    private static IListType GetListTypeAsEnum<T>() where T : class
    {
        IListType rtType = IListType.Unknown;      
        Type inListType = typeof(T);

        if (inListType == typeof(IXList))
        {
            rtType = IListType.X;
        }
        else if (inListType == typeof(IYList))
        {
            rtType = IListType.Y;
        }
        return rtType;
    }

    private static IntPtr DoGetItemforList<T>(T list, ref Guid guid) where T : class
    {
        IntPtr itemPointer;
        if (list == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("end of list");
        }
        switch (GetListTypeAsEnum<T>())
        {
            case IListType.X:
                ((IXList)list).GetItem(ref guid, out itemPointer);
                break;
            case IListType.Y:
                ((IYList)list).GetItem(ref guid, out itemPointer);
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("unknown passed type");
        }
        return itemPointer;
    }

    private static void DoHeadforList<T>(T list) where T : class
    {
        if (list == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("end of list");
        }
        switch (GetListTypeAsEnum<T>())
        {
            case IListType.X:
                ((IXList)list).Head();
                break;
            case IListType.Y:
                ((IYList)list).Head();
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("unknown passed type");
        }
    }

    private static void DoNextforList<T>(T list) where T : class
    {
        if (list == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("end of list");
        }
        switch (GetListTypeAsEnum<T>())
        {
            case IListType.X:
                ((IXList)list).Next();
                break;
            case IListType.Y:
                ((IYList)list).Next();
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("unknown passed type");
        }
    }
```